# How do I revert iTunes contact sync?

Tags: iphone, itunes, contacts

I first upgraded my operating system (Windows Vista) and then iTunes.

During the upgrade, I accidentally chose contact syncing should prefer my Windows' contacts over my iPhone's contacts. Now I've lost my phone's contact directory.

How do I revert the iTunes contact sync so I can get my iPhone contacts back?

Comment: Are you saying that you wiped all your iPhone contacts during an iTunes sync after you upgraded to Windows Vista? Are they stored/backuped in any other place at all?

Answer (score -1):

I'm Michael and I work for connex.io, an address book app.

You can probably retrieve your contacts by taking the following steps:

1. On your iPhone go to Settings -> iCloud
2. and disable ‘Contacts’

They should re-appear.

If you want your contacts to be safer, you can always try [connex.io](https://connex.io/). With our service you will always have your contacts with you. So even if you lose your phone, your contacts will still be in the cloud. It can also sync, de-duplicate, merge, clean, complete and update all of your contacts automatically. So you connect your devices once and then you will always have your contacts where ever you need them. If you would like to try it out, check out [this link](https://connex.io/tour-1-what-does-connexio-do) or you can send me an e-mail at michael@connex.io